# Multiple Regression Python

Tags: python, regression

I really don't understand what's wrong with my (simple) code...

i just want to test a multiple linear regression (....!).

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import scipy.stats as st
 import sklearn
 n = 1000

 X1 = linspace(2, 8.5, n)
 X2 = linspace(-4, 2.9, n)
 X3 = linspace(-1, 16, n)

 X = np.transpose( [X1, X2, X3] )

 Y = 2*X1 + 3.2*X2 -1.2*X3  +  4  + st.norm.rvs(size = n, loc = 0, scale = 0.6)

 X = pd.DataFrame( X , columns = ["X1", "X2", "X3"])
 Y = pd.DataFrame(Y, columns = ["Y"])

 #Create linear regression object:
 my_reg = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()

 #Train:
 my_reg.fit(X, Y)

 print('Coefficients: \n', my_reg.coef_)
 print('Constant: \n', my_reg.intercept_)
```

And I get some stupid results, like the coefficients are [ 0.25127347  0.26673645  0.65717676] ...

I also tried the OLS way, but I still get non sense coef (slighty different but still stupid)

(It's work with a one variable linear regression, something like Y = 2*X + 5, I would get coef and intercept really close to real one)

Comment: It is customary here to include all necessary import statements to make sure everyone who wants to help you can do so easily. Please consider editing your post accordingly.

Comment: I think the main issue is that your matrix is nearly rank-deficient. Your `X1` and `X2` are so strongly collinear that numerical results become unreliable. My guess is that if you add noise to these columns, you will get the "real" coefficients. The key word here is multicollinearity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the coefficients do not at all resemble the "true" ones that you have set indicates that multicollinearity might be a problem. The issue with your code is that your `X` matrix is near-singular, which renders numerical results instable. As can be seen in @R.yan's graphs, your `X1` and `X2` are almost identical except for a linear shift. This is corroborated by the fact that your `X` matrix, which has 1000 rows and three columns, only has a rank of 2. See:

```
np.linalg.matrix_rank(X)
Out[26]: 2
```

Try the following instead:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
n = 1000

# adding noise to your data:
X1 = np.linspace(2, 8.5, n) + st.norm.rvs(size=n ,loc = 0, scale = 1)
X2 = np.linspace(-4, 2.9, n) + st.norm.rvs(size=n ,loc = 0, scale = 1)
X3 = np.linspace(-1, 16, n) + st.norm.rvs(size=n ,loc = 0, scale = 1)

X = np.transpose( [X1, X2, X3] )

Y = 2*X1 + 3.2*X2 -1.2*X3  +  4  + st.norm.rvs(size=1000 ,loc = 0, scale = 1)

X = pd.DataFrame( X , columns = ["X1", "X2", "X3"])
Y = pd.DataFrame(Y, columns = ["Y"])
#Create linear regression object:
my_reg = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept = True)

#Train:
res = my_reg.fit(X, Y)

print('Coefficients: \n', my_reg.coef_)
print('Constant: \n', my_reg.intercept_)

Coefficients: 
 [[ 1.99273588  3.20068392 -1.19688422]]
Constant: 
 [ 4.02296003]
```

Now, we get the right coefficients, and a matrix of full rank:

```
np.linalg.matrix_rank(X)
Out[32]: 3
```

Note that in linear regression, `X` needs to have a rank equal to the number of columns (or rows, if that is less). If it does not, this means there is multicollinearity, which renders numerical results for the inverse of `X'X` instable (depending on which algorithm is used). See [this description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) for more information on multicollinearity.

Comment: Nice explanation:)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks all!

I didn't perform a linear reression for a while, and of course it's because X is not invertible (in R, it gives me 'nan').

So it wasn't a smart question...

Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, I am quite surprised that there is no built-in check in `sklearn`, as there is in `R`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the code gives you the correct answer. I plot the predicted Y base on the coef_ and intercept_ from your regression and have the following graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = 1000

X1 = np.linspace(2, 8.5, n)
X2 = np.linspace(-4, 2.9, n)
X3 = np.linspace(-1, 16, n)

X = np.transpose( [X1, X2, X3] )

Y = 2*X1 + 3.2*X2 -1.2*X3  +  4  + st.norm.rvs(size=1000 ,loc = 0, scale = 0.6)

X = pd.DataFrame( X , columns = ["X1", "X2", "X3"])
Y = pd.DataFrame(Y, columns = ["Y"])
#Create linear regression object:
my_reg = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()
plt.plot(Y, color='blue', label='Y')
#Train:
res = my_reg.fit(X, Y)

print('Coefficients: \n', my_reg.coef_)
print('Constant: \n', my_reg.intercept_)

plt.scatter(X.index.values,X['X1'], c='black')
plt.scatter(X.index.values,X['X2'], c='black')
plt.scatter(X.index.values,X['X3'], c='black')


Y_pred = my_reg.coef_[0][0]*X['X1'] + my_reg.coef_[0][1]*X['X2'] +my_reg.coef_[0][2]*X['X3'] + my_reg.intercept_
plt.plot(Y_pred, color="red", label='predict')
plt.legend()

Out[]: ('Coefficients: \n', array([[  3.13842691e+12,   1.01316187e+13,  -5.31223199e+12]]))
('Constant: \n', array([  2.89373889e+13]))
```

[image]